# Failed to to turn django staff flag on programatically

Tags: python, django

I am fetching user from database then `is_staff=True` then saving it. But yet it fails save.

Why can't I save a user as staff pragmatically using this code?

```
def approve_staff(self,request,username,):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        u=User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if u.exists():
            u[0].is_staff=True;
            u[0].save() #
            print u[0],u[0].is_staff
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails" ? Do you have a traceback ?

Comment: it always prints false. so i mean is_staff for that user is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it will necessarily solve your problem, but the Django way to get a single record is `Queryset.get`

```
    try:
        u=User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404() 
    u.is_staff=True;
    u.save() #
    print u, u.is_staff
```

Also your view should only accept POST requests.

Comment: solved :). But why my code did not work, can you help me to understand that?

Comment: Because you get a new object from the database every time you slice a queryset.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks fro the explanation - I suspected something like this but didn't have a django install at hand to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do a

```
User.objects.filter(username=username).update(is_staff=True)
```

It will update the data (without having to call save()) for every object the filter finds.

Comment: works, but in term of number of queries not the best way of doing what I want to do, I THINK.

Comment: Isn't that done hiting the db a single time? The only problem my solution may create, IMHO, is that .update() directly works on the db without calling the signals or update the auto_now fields, but I suppose in such a case, it doesn't matter.